# Ayuda con programa de encuesta JAVA

Tags: java, array

me podrian ayudar por favor con este codigo, no termino de entender **por que me da este error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

Aparte de eso si me pueden ayudar dandome algunas ideas de como terminarlo porque no entiendo como hacerlo bien. **Muchas gracias!**

**Estas son las consignas:**

> Ejercicio 2: Carga de Encuesta Escribir una función que solicite al
>   usuario la calificación de 6 atracciones distintas del parque
>   denominadas: A1, A2, A3, A4 y A5. Las calificaciones van del 1 al 10
>   (1 es pésimo y 10 es excelente o inmejorable). Los aspectos son:
>   • Grado de Diversión: es la atracción divertida o aburrida. • Calidad
>   de la Atracción: La atracción incluye características que la resaltan:
>   luces, colores, etc. •    Justicia del precio: es el costo de entrada a
>   la atracción justo. • Atención de los empleados: El personal que se
>   encuentra en la atracción es amigable. Solicite las calificaciones al
>   usuario y luego imprima la calificación promedio de cada una de las
>   distintas atracciones.

```
  int quiz[]= new int[4], total[]= new int[6], fnl;

            for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {

                System.out.println("Atraccion A"+ (i+1) + ":");

                for (int x=0; x<4; x++) {
                    if (x == 0) {
                        System.out.println("•\tGrado de Diversión: es la atracción divertida o aburrida.");
                        quiz[x] = sc.nextInt();
                    } else if (x == 1) {
                        System.out.println("•\tCalidad de la Atracción: La atracción incluye características que la resaltan: luces, colores, etc.");
                        quiz[x] = sc.nextInt();
                    } else if (x == 2) {
                        System.out.println("•\tJusticia del precio: es el costo de entrada a la atracción justo.");
                        quiz[x] = sc.nextInt();
                    } else if (x == 3) {
                        System.out.println("•\tAtención de los empleados: El personal que se encuentra en la atracción es amigable.");
                        quiz[x] = sc.nextInt();
                    }

                }

                total[i] = quiz[i]+total[i];

            total[i]= total[i]/4;
            }
```

Comment: Buenas compañero @Josias99 este error te ocurre como te indica el log porque le asignas un indice superior a tu vector/array

Comment: eso seria cuando la variable `i` del `for(int i=0; i<6; i++)` vale `4` y se lo asignas a tu vector `quiz[i]` en la parte de `total[i] = quiz[i]+total[i];` y emite el error porque tu vector `quiz[]` se definio con 4 indices el `0,1,2,3` en esta aparte `int quiz[]= new int[4]`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ayuda con Programa en JAVA : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197522/ayuda-con-programa-en-java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 1):

El error ocurre cuando tratas de acceder al valor con índice 4 del arreglo `quiz`, ya que el arreglo `quiz` solo tiene hasta el índice 3 (índices válidos 0,1,2,3).

La corrección es poner el manejador de índice correcto `x` a `quiz`, y ponerlo dentro del segundo for.

```
int quiz[]= new int[4], total[]= new int[6], fnl;

for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {

    System.out.println("Atraccion A"+ (i+1) + ":");

    for (int x=0; x<4; x++) {
        if (x == 0) {
            System.out.println("•\tGrado de Diversión: es la atracción divertida o aburrida.");
            quiz[x] = sc.nextInt();
        } else if (x == 1) {
            System.out.println("•\tCalidad de la Atracción: La atracción incluye características que la resaltan: luces, colores, etc.");
            quiz[x] = sc.nextInt();
        } else if (x == 2) {
            System.out.println("•\tJusticia del precio: es el costo de entrada a la atracción justo.");
            quiz[x] = sc.nextInt();
        } else if (x == 3) {
            System.out.println("•\tAtención de los empleados: El personal que se encuentra en la atracción es amigable.");
            quiz[x] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        total[i] = quiz[x]+total[i];
    }

    total[i]= total[i]/4;
}
```