# Ayuda con Programa en JAVA : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que simula ser una Agenda de Contactos, el problema es que al agregarle más datos al `ArrayList` el programa no me funciona:

```
public ArrayList<modeloPersona> LeerTodoArchivo(String Archivo){
    ArrayList<modeloPersona> personaArreglo = new  ArrayList<modeloPersona>();
    modeloPersona persona; 

    try {
        File file = new File(Archivo);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String linea;
        while ((linea = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {       
            String[] partes = linea.split(",");
            persona = new modeloPersona();//SE CONSTRUYE
            persona.setNombre(partes[0]);
            persona.setTelefono(partes[1]);
            persona.setDireccion(partes[2]);
            // persona.setEdad(partes[3]);
            // persona.setComentario(partes[4]);

            personaArreglo.add(persona);        
        }
        fileReader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return personaArreglo;
}
```

El problema es que al agregar por ejemplo un:

`persona.setEdad(partes[3]);` y `persona.setComentario(partes[4]);`

No me deja, sólo me deja tener tres posiciones del 0 al 2.

Me muestra el error

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Que no tendria que ser `persona.setEdad(partes[3]);`?

Comment: ¿No sería `persona.setEdad(partes[3])`? Para asignar un objeto se usa el método `set()`, y para recogerlas se usa el método `get()`. ¿Nos podrías dar el mensaje de error para que te podamos ayudar?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus por el uso EXCESIVO de get y set, es Java...

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Una vez que leas todo eso, me podes explicar porque queres acceder a un elemento que no existiria? los vectores son Zero Based, eso quiere decir que el primer item es el 0. tu linea tiene mas de 3 items?

Comment: Si es correcto,la linea tiene mas de 3 items, pero al colocar esas otras dos posiciones me tira error, en la linea ingresada.

Comment: podes mostrarnos la linea, y fijarte que dice el debug sobre el contenido de tu variable partes

Comment: El fallo estará en el constructor de la clase Persona. Échale un vistazo o ponlo por aquí.

Comment: @gbianchi "por el uso EXCESIVO de get y set, es Java.." hahaha =D

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que cada linea del archivo tenga suficientes separaciones por coma? El error que muestra quiere decir que el index del array no existe (en este caso 3 y 4). Yo te recomendaría debuguear para ver qué valores recoge el array `partes`.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Por qué se produce un java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247104/por-qu%c3%a9-se-produce-un-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que el contenido de linea contiene 3 elementos separados por "," , ejemplo:

```
 linea = "palabra0, palabra1, palabra2";
 String[] partes = linea.split(",");
```

por lo tanto solo puedes obtener los elementos:

```
partes[0] = "palabra0";
partes[1] = "palabra1";
partes[2] = "palabra2";
```

Si el contenido de linea tuviera 5 elementos separados por ",",

```
 linea = "palabra0, palabra1, palabra2, palabra3, palabra4";
 String[] partes = linea.split(",");
```

entonces podrías obtener los elementos con indice 3 y 4 :

```
partes[0] = "palabra0";
partes[1] = "palabra1";
partes[2] = "palabra2";
partes[3] = "palabra3";
partes[4] = "palabra4";
```

**Debes asegurar que las lineas del archivo que tratas de leer tengan 5 elementos separados por ",".**

---

**Puedes validar también el caso en el cual no se encuentren los elementos del array**, en este caso los elementos no se agregarían al objeto:

```
   ...
   ...
    while ((linea = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] partes = linea.split(",");
        persona = new modeloPersona();//SE CONSTRUYE

        if(partes.length >0) {
            persona.setNombre(partes[0]);
        }
        if (partes.length >1){
            persona.setTelefono(partes[1]);
        }
        if (partes.length >2){
           persona.setDireccion(partes[2]);
        }
        if (partes.length >3){
           persona.setEdad(partes[3]);
        }
        if (partes.length >4) {
            persona.setComentario(partes[4]);
        }

        personaArreglo.add(persona);

    }
  ...
  ...
```