# ¿Por qué se produce un java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, ordenamiento

Estoy intentado hacer un miniprograma que ordena los números de forma ascendente. ¿Alguien me explica porque me da error el código?. Gracias.

```
package ejerciciosJava;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class OrdenarNúmeros {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int contador = 0, num, a = 0, i, j;
        int[] numeros = new int[5];

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            System.out.println("Introduzca valores (0 para finalizar): ");
            num = teclado.nextInt();

            if (num != 0) {
                numeros[contador] = num;
                contador++;
            }
        }while (num != 0);

        for (i = 0; numeros.length > i; i++) {
            for (j = 0; numeros.length > j; j++) {
                if (numeros[j] < numeros[j + 1]) { //JUSTO AQUÍ ME DA EL ERROR!!
                    a = numeros[j];
                    numeros[j] = numeros[j + 1];
                    numeros[j+ 1] = a;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(numeros[i] + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu error es conocido como [OBOE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) por las siglas en inglés *Off By One*, es decir, que estás mandando un valor incorrecto por una unidad.

En tu caso, estás diciendo en la condición que `tamañoDelArreglo > indice` lo cual es una condificón correcta pero al llegar a la condición

```
if (arreglo[indice] < arreglo[indice + 1]) {
```

el tamaño del arreglo es `n` espacios, y el tamaño de `indice` en la última iteración es `n-1` convirtiéndose en

```
if (arreglo[n-1] < arreglo[n-1+ 1]) {
```

que se simplifica en

```
if (arreglo[n-1] < arreglo[n]) {
```

[image: tamaño]

si n es 10, es decir, si el arreglo puede tener 10 elementos, como se cuentan desde el índice 0, el máximo índice que puedes tener es 9, por lo que `arreglo[n]` es imposible que exista y de allí que te de un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` es decir, traducido dice "excepción de índice de arreglo fuera de los límites"

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar, me da el mismo error :/.

Comment: en la pregunta querías saber a qué se debía el error, nunca te dí una solución por el simple hecho de que no la pediste

Comment: Si me echas una mano, te lo agredeceria mucho :). Estoy muy rayado de porque no me sale.

Comment: @x140l1n tal vez deberías de hacer otra pregunta para saber como se resuelve y no solamente el por qué sucede