# System.out.print() imprime dos veces

Tags: java, poo

Tengo el siguiente código java, la clase Pruebas contiene el main donde se hace uso de la clase de mas abajo "Empleados",creo unos empleados, luego solicito al usuario que ingrese la cantidad que quiera y ahi me da un extraño error, no entiendo por qué se imprime dos veces el `System.out.print("ing nombre:")` dentro del bucle for, el output sale así **"ing nombre:ing nombre:"** pero solo la primera vez, la siguiente vuelta del bucle ya se imprime normal como aparece en la salida

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Pruebas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Empleados emp1=new Empleados("pedro");
        Empleados emp2=new Empleados("cristofer");
        System.out.println(emp1.devuelveDatos());
        System.out.println(emp2.devuelveDatos());
        emp1.cambiaSeccion("Jefe");
        System.out.println(emp1.devuelveDatos());
        
        Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre="";
        System.out.print("ctos empleados desea ing: ");
        int x=inp.nextInt();
        Empleados[] e=new Empleados[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.print("ing nombre:");
            nombre=inp.nextLine();
            e[i]=new Empleados(nombre);
        }
        for(Empleados emp:e){
            System.out.println(emp.devuelveDatos());
        }
//OUTPUT:
//        Nombre: pedro |Seccion: Administracion |Id: 1
//        Nombre: cristofer |Seccion: Administracion |Id: 2
//        Nombre: pedro |Seccion: Jefe |Id: 1
//        ctos empleados desea ing: 3
//        ing nombre:ing nombre:lolo
//        ing nombre:maria
//        Nombre:  |Seccion: Administracion |Id: 3
//        Nombre: lolo |Seccion: Administracion |Id: 4
//        Nombre: maria |Seccion: Administracion |Id: 5
    }
}

//los trabajadores parten en administracion, luego desde ahi van escalando
class Empleados{
    //campos ejemplar
    private final String nombre; //el nombre no cambia por lo que lo declaramos como constante (final)
    private String seccion;
    private int Id; //cada objeto tendra su copia que puede ser distinta, es privada por tanto no accedible si no es por metodo
    private static int IdCorrelativo=1; //solo la clase tendra una copia de esta variable
            
    //CONSTRUCTOR:
    public Empleados(String nom){
        nombre=nom;
        seccion="Administracion";   
        Id=IdCorrelativo; //la copia de la variable id para cada objeto sera el valor que almacene la clase en su variable Idcorrelativo
        IdCorrelativo++; //el id de la clase se irá incrementando por cada objeto creado el cual tendra su propia copia de dicho id correlativo
    }
    
    public void cambiaSeccion(String seccion){
        this.seccion=seccion; //this permite diferenciar el campo de clase (sección) con el argumento (tiene el mismo nombre) 
    }
    
    //getter q nos devuelva la info del trabajador:
    public String devuelveDatos(){
        return "Nombre: "+nombre+" |Seccion: "+seccion+" |Id: "+Id;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: tu ciclo inicia desde cero, así que cuenta 0, 1, 2, 3 y por eso hace una pasada de más siempre. Es decir, un OBOE

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué se produce un java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247104/por-qu%c3%a9-se-produce-un-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que me parece es que queda un "enter" en el buffer de entrada después de leer el int que es la cantidad de elementos a ingresar en el loop.

Y cuando entra al bucle, el ingreso del primer nombre está vacío porque se lee ese enter que había quedado olvidado en el buffer.

Probá agregando la lectura de la linea después de leer el int:

```
Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
String nombre="";
System.out.print("ctos empleados desea ing: ");
int x=inp.nextInt();

inp.nextLine(); // <----- si hay enter olvidado, este lo debe leer


Empleados[] e=new Empleados[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    System.out.print("ing nombre:");
    nombre=inp.nextLine();
    e[i]=new Empleados(nombre);
 }
```

Comment: Eso era, agregué la linea que indicas y solucioné el error, nunca me había pasado esto de un enter fantasma, no es problema de mi código entonces (?)