# Java, error "Index 4 out of bounds for length 4"

Tags: java

Tengo escritas un par de funciones las cuales ambas me dan el mismo error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4

No entiendo cual es el problema lo he buscado en internet pero aún así no lo entiendo.

El código en cuestión es este:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class examen2019 {
    static int[] imagenEspejo(int[] arr){
        int i;
        int[] result = new int[arr.length*2];
        
        for(i=0;i<=arr.length*2;i++){
            if( i<=arr.length){
                result[i]= arr[i];
            }else{
                
                result[i]= arr[i-arr.length];

            } 

        }return result;

    }

    static boolean alMenosDos(int[] arr, int n){
        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean result= false;
        for(i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
            if (n== arr[i]){
                j++;
            }
            if (j>= 2){
                result= true;
            }

        }return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] arr={1,2,4,5};
        System.out.println(imagenEspejo(arr));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ayuda con Programa en JAVA : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197522/ayuda-con-programa-en-java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error se lanza para indicar que se ha accedido a una matriz o array con un índice ilegal. El índice es negativo o mayor o igual que el tamaño de la matriz o array.

Por ejemplo: tu tienes un array de 4 elementos y tratas de acceder al índice 4, esto te causará error por que los arreglos comienzan con índice 0, entonces

```
   indice         posicion
     0                1
     1                2
     2                3
     3                4
     4                x //Causaría un error
```

Por este motivo cuando inicias un ciclo for y empiezas a contar de posición 0 debes de validar que sea menor al length del array.

Tú código solo necesita un ajuste en los ciclos.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class examen2019 {
     static int[] imagenEspejo(int[] arr){
    int i;
    int[] result = new int[arr.length*2];
    
    for(i=0;i<arr.length*2;i++){ //Se quita el =
        if( i<arr.length){ //Quitamos =
            result[i]= arr[i];
        }else{
            
            result[i]= arr[i-arr.length];
        } 

    }return result;

}

static boolean alMenosDos(int[] arr, int n){
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    boolean result= false;
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ //Quitamos =
        if (n== arr[i]){
            j++;
        }
        if (j>= 2){
            result= true;
        }

    }return result;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr={1,2,4,5};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(imagenEspejo(arr)));
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me los has aclarado muy bien. Gracias

Comment: De favor @antoniojimenez si te ha servido la respuesta, indica que es la correcta.Gracias