# Tengo este Problema al realizar un crud entre java y mysql me sale este erro al actualizar un registro

Tags: java, mysql, crud

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el método

```
public void ActualizarDatos(){
    
    try {
        
        String SQL="update autor set cod_escritor=?, nom_escritor=?, cod_libro=?, sexo=? where cod_escritor=?";
        
        int filaselecionada=TablaDatos.getSelectedRow();
        String dao=(String)TablaDatos.getValueAt(filaselecionada, 0);
        PreparedStatement pst=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        
        pst.setString(1,txtcodigo.getText());
        pst.setString(2,txtnombre.getText());
        pst.setString(3,txtcodlibro.getText());
        int seleccionado1 = cbsexo.getSelectedIndex();
        pst.setString(4, cbsexo.getItemAt(seleccionado1));
        
        pst.setString(5, dao);
        pst.execute();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Actuializado Correctamente");

        
    }catch (Exception e) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de Actualizacion: "+e.getMessage());
    }  
}
```

ese es el mismo método que use con otra tabla y funciono a la perfección alguien me puede ayudar.

---

Index -1 out of bounds for length 10 Este es el error y también me sale con el método eliminar, que es este:

```
public void eliminarRegistros(){
    
    int filSeleccionada = TablaDatos.getSelectedRow();
    
    try {
        String SQL="delete from autor where codigo="+TablaDatos.getValueAt(filSeleccionada,0);
        
        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        
        int n=st.executeUpdate(SQL);
        
        if (n>=0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Eliminado Exitosamente");
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al  Elimiar: "+e.getMessage());
    
    }
    
}
```

presiento que el código esta bien por que en el otro crud es exactamente igual nada mas cambiando los nombres y en el otro si lo hace sin errores

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Java, error "Index 4 out of bounds for length 4"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413098/java-error-index-4-out-of-bounds-for-length-4)

Comment: Me parece que el candidato para que ocurra el error está en la línea: `cbsexo.getItemAt(seleccionado1))`  fíjate que valor tiene `seleccionado1`  o si realmente está seleccionado. Aunque también puede está en `filaSeleccionada`. Uno de los dos está con un índice fuera del rango.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! depura el programa y fijate donde exactamente esta el error. Ese try catch de esa forma, no sirve absolutamente para nada si no te da la informacion concreta del problema