# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al llenar las posiciones de un array por medio de Scanner en java

Tags: java

He estado intentando hacer un programa para calcular el promedio de unas notas, una de las condiciones es guardar las notas en un vector. Este es el codigo que he realizado hasta el momento:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Promedios{

    public int nota;
    public float promedionota;
    public int numnota;
    public int notas[] = new int[numnota];
    public int posnota;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void entradas(){
        System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el número de notas:");
        numnota= in.nextInt();

        for(posnota=1;posnota<=numnota;posnota++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de la nota número " + posnota);
        notas[posnota]= in.nextInt();
        }
    }

}
```

Pero a la hora de compilar me sale el siguiente error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0"

Este error se me genera a la hora de ingresar el valor de nota.

Comment: Hola Julian. Verás, cuando declaras una variable sin valor, en tu caso la variable numnota, por defecto java le asigna el valor 0. Al declarar posteriormente el array notas, le estás diciendo que tendrá 0 valores, por lo que al introducir luego un valor, te saldrá la excepción, pues estás introduciendo valores en un objeto, el array, que previamente has indicado que no los tendrá. La forma correcta sería declarar el array después de pedir el número de notas y recoger las mismas en la variable numnota

Comment: despues de obtener el valor de numnota con el scanner,recien declara el array ,ten presente que lo indices en un array  parten de 0,por lo que tu for deberia partir de 0,`for(posnota=0;posnota<numnota;posnota++)`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ayuda con Programa en JAVA : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197522/ayuda-con-programa-en-java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: PD: los arreglos inician en la posicion 0

Answer (score 0):

como ya te han dicho cuando creas el array le estas dando una longitud de 0 , que es el valor que le da Java por defecto a tu variable **numnota** al no haberla inicializado.
Tienes que otorgarle el valor a la variable que usas para el tamaño del array antes de crear el array. Recuerda que los arrays no son dinamicos y una vez le das un tamaño no lo puedes modificar.

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentaron, los arreglos son estáticos, entonces debes incializarlo una vez que conozcas la dimensión que va a tener

```
public class Promedios{

    public int nota;
    public float promedionota;
    public int numnota;
    public int notas[];
    public int posnota;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void entradas(){
        System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el número de notas:");
        numnota= in.nextInt();
        notas[] = new int[numnota];
        for(posnota=1;posnota<=numnota;posnota++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de la nota número " + posnota);
        notas[posnota]= in.nextInt();
        }
    }

}
```