# Error al ejecutar código java, Index 4 out of bounds for length 4

Tags: java, bucle-for

tengo el siguiente código:

```
public double[] llegirDades() {
    teclat=new Scanner(System.in);
    double arrayNotes[]=new double[4];
    System.out.println(" A continuacio introdueixi les 5 notes:");

    for(int i=0;i<=arrayNotes.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(" Nota "+i+": ");
        
        boolean llegit=false;
        
        while(!llegit) {
            llegit=teclat.hasNextDouble();
            
            if(llegit) {
                arrayNotes[i]=teclat.nextDouble();
            
            }else {     
                System.out.print("El valor introduit no es un real, torna-ho a provar: ");
                teclat.next();
            }
        }
    }
    
    calculaMax();
    return arrayNotes;
}

public double calculaMax() {
    double MAX=0;
    double arrayNotes1[]=new double[4];
    
    arrayNotes1 = llegirDades();
    
    for(int i=1;i<=arrayNotes1.length-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<arrayNotes1.length;j++) {
            if(arrayNotes1[i]<arrayNotes1[j]) {
                arrayNotes1[j]=MAX;
            }                               
        }           
    }
    
    imprimir();
    return MAX;
}       

public void imprimir() {
    double max=calculaMax();        
    System.out.print("La nota maxima es: "+max);            
}
```

Al ejecutar me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
    at test.test.llegirDades(test.java:35)
    at test.test.mostrarMenu(test.java:19)
    at test.test.main(test.java:12)
```

La línea 35 coincide con el `arrayNotes[i]=teclat.nextDouble()`;

No veo donde está el error.
He probado a ir eliminando partes del código, pero sigue fallando y yo sigo sin ver por qué.

Comment: Hola Sergi, el error es sutil... pero fatal, en la condición del for pones  *int i = 0;  i **<=** arrayNotes.length; i++*,  y debería ser *int i = 0;  i **<** arrayNotes.length; i++*

Comment: Nota que el primer elemento contado (length) es 1, mientras que el primer elemento de un arreglo tiene índice 0; por lo tanto, el último elemento n se encuentra en el índice n-1.

Comment: Hola, primero gracias por contestar! Marce, si quito el = y pongo solo i<arrayNotes.length solo me permite introducir 4 notas, no 5 como pido (de indice 0 a 4)  y me solicita la introducción de esas 4 notas en bucle infinito.

Comment: En realidad , al ejecutar , me permite introducir los "5" double que pido , pero al pulsar intro tras introducir el 5º es cuando me da error

Comment: Sergi, cuando declaraste el array lo hiciste así: **double arrayNotes[] = new double[ 4 ];**, si queres recibir 5 notas debes hacerlo así: **double arrayNotes[] = new double[ 5 ];**, es fácil confundirse, por otro lado, cuando haces un comentario para alguien, acordate de poner **@nombreUsuario**, así recibe la notificación.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ayuda con Programa en JAVA : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197522/ayuda-con-programa-en-java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marce Puente no recordé  que en la declaración del array no se tiene en cuenta las posiciones de indentación sinó simplemente el número de valores sin contar el 0. Fallo de novato!

Comment: @Sergi, te sorprendería la cantidad de errores "de novato" que cometo!! jeje.

Comment: Hola @Marce Puente, sobre el mismo código , al modificarlo y ejecutar me encuentro con un bucle "infinito" donde se repite este primer FOR donde solicito la entrada de 5 notas. Al terminar de introducir las cinco notas me vuelve a iniciar el loop. No veo a que es debido. GRACIAS

Comment: Sergi, tienes un bucle while un poco confuso dentro de ese FOR, es posible que estes ejecutando de forma infinita el while en lugar del for?

Comment: Hola @Grismak , si elimino del código todo el WHILE y no lo condiciono (lo uso para garantizar que se introduce un double) me sigue reiniciando el bucle FOR

Comment: Me dices que si haces for(int i=0;i<arrayNotes.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(" Nota "+i+": "); } en el log esto se hace un bucle infinito?

Comment: @Grismak , si, acabo de probarlo y si lo hago como muestro en el siguiente código, me lo sigue haciendo... No logro comprenderlo.                          
      for(int i=0;i<arrayNotes.length;i++) {
    
    System.out.print(" Nota "+(i+1)+": ");
   
      arrayNotes[i]=teclat.nextDouble();
     }
      calculaMax();
           return arrayNotes;
    }

Comment: Será por el   arrayNotes1 = llegirDades();     del siguiente método?

Comment: @Grismark , Hola acabo de fijarme en algo, no es que repita el FOR, lo que sucede es que me repite el método entero de forma indefinida ya que me pide que ingrese las 5 notas, y eso esta antes de entrar en el FOR .

Comment: Hay un ciclo infinito porque `imprimir` llama a `calculaMax` que en la penúltima línea llama nuevamente a `imprimir`.

Comment: Bien visto @GavilanPatagonico

Answer (score 0):

```
public double[] llegirDades() {
   Scanner teclat = new Scanner( System.in );
   double arrayNotes[] = new double[ 5 ];
   System.out.println( " A continuacio introdueixi les 5 notes:" );
   for( int i = 0; i < arrayNotes.length; i++ ) {
      System.out.print( " Nota " + i + ": " );
      boolean llegit = false;
      while( ! llegit ) {
         llegit = teclat.hasNextDouble();
         if( llegit ) {
            arrayNotes[ i ] = teclat.nextDouble();
         }
         else {
            System.out.print( "El valor introduit no es un real, torna-ho a provar: " );
            teclat.next();
         }
      }
   }
   return arrayNotes;
}

public void calculaMax() {
   double MAX = 0;
   double arrayNotes1[] = llegirDades();
   for( int i = 1; i <= arrayNotes1.length - 1; i++ ) {
      for( int j = 0; j < arrayNotes1.length; j++ ) {
         if( MAX < arrayNotes1[ j ] ) {
             MAX = arrayNotes1[ j ];
         }
      }
   }
   imprimir( MAX );
}

public void imprimir( double max ) {
   System.out.print( "La nota maxima es: " + max );
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Principales pri = new Principales();
   Herramientas her = new Herramientas();
   her.calculaMax();
}
```

Bueno, vamos con las correcciones, como ya vimos en los comentarios, el primer problema era está linea:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= arrayNotes.length; i++ ) {
```

el "**<=**" en la condición, hace que nos lance una excepción, debemos usar "**<**".
Corregido eso, nos encontramos con un "embrollo" de llamadas entre métodos, que como bien marcó @GavilanPatagonico, nos producen un bucle infinito.
Para evitar este, quitamos de **llegirDades**, la llamada a **calculaMax**, ya que **llegirDades** devuelve un double, y es lo que usaremos.
A **calculaMax** lo hacemos void, ya que no necesitamos que devuelva nada (debemos quitar el return).
Dentro de **calculaMax**, instanciamos **arrayNotes1** con lo que nos devuelve **llegirDades**.
Dentro del *for* tenemos otro problemita, el código en el cuerpo del *if* está invertido, debería ser:

```
MAX = arrayNotes1[ j ];
```

osea que cuando la nota actual, sea mayor que la que tenemos en *MAX*, *MAX* cambie su valor por esta.
Por último, llamamos a **imprimir** pasandole como parámetro *MAX*.