# Porque me reinicia el loop (ciclo FOR)?¿

Tags: java, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente código, al ejecutar me permite cargar las 5 notas que pido, pero en lugar de saltar al siguiente método y calcularme la nota máxima, al terminar de introducir la quinta nota, me reinicia el ciclo for y me vuelve a pedir que introduzca las 5 notas y así sucesivamente...

Añado que eliminando el WHILE (y su contenido) me sigue fallando.

GRACIAS!

```
    public double[] llegirDades() {
        
        teclat=new Scanner(System.in);
        double arrayNotes[]=new double[5];
        System.out.println(" A continuacio introdueixi les 5 notes:");
        for(int i=0;i<arrayNotes.length;i++) {              
            
            System.out.print(" Nota "+(i+1)+": ");
            
            boolean llegit=false;
            
            while(!llegit) {                
                llegit=teclat.hasNextDouble();                  
                if(llegit) {                        
                    arrayNotes[i]=teclat.nextDouble();
                
                }else {     
                    
                    System.out.print("El valor introduit no es un real, torna-ho a provar: ");
                    teclat.next();
                }
            }               
        }           
        calculaMax();
        return arrayNotes;
    }
    
    public double calculaMax() {
        
        double MAX=0;
        double arrayNotes1[]=new double[5];
        
        arrayNotes1=llegirDades();
        
        for(int i=1;i<arrayNotes1.length-1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<arrayNotes1.length;j++) {
                
                if(arrayNotes1[i]<arrayNotes1[j]) {
                    
                    arrayNotes1[j]=MAX;
                }                               
            }           
        }
        
        imprimir();
        return MAX;
    }       
    
    public void imprimir() {    
    
        double max=calculaMax();    
                
        System.out.print("La nota maxima es: "+max);            
    }               
}
```

Comment: Hola sergi, tienes una pregunta con el mismo código de hace unas horas https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582846/error-al-ejecutar-c%c3%b3digo-java-index-4-out-of-bounds-for-length-4 donde además, emplazas esta pregunta en los comentarios, deberías hacer un edit de esa pregunta con el código modificado en vez de generar una nueva issue. sobre todo porque este código no esta modificado y seguira dandote el outOfBounds

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al ejecutar código java, Index 4 out of bounds for length 4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582846/error-al-ejecutar-c%c3%b3digo-java-index-4-out-of-bounds-for-length-4)

Comment: Creo que resolví el intríngulis en la otra pregunta. Los métodos se invocan entre sí.

Comment: El problema es que hay llamadas anidadas. `imprimir` invoca a `calculaMax`, el cual llama a `llegirDades` que ejecuta el ciclo `for`, que al terminar devuelve el control a `calculaMax`. Pero `calculaMax` en su penúltima línea llama a `imprimir`, que a su vez llama a `calculaMax` y así sucesivamente. Quitar la llamada a `imprimir` en `calculaMax` resuelve el problema.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es retirar la llamada a la función calculaMax dentro del método llegirDades. La función calculaMax ya se llama desde el método imprimir. El código quedaría así:

```
public double[] llegirDades() {
        
        teclat=new Scanner(System.in);
        double arrayNotes[]=new double[5];
        System.out.println(" A continuacio introdueixi les 5 notes:");
        for(int i=0;i<arrayNotes.length;i++) {              
            
            System.out.print(" Nota "+(i+1)+": ");
            
            boolean llegit=false;
            
            while(!llegit) {                
                llegit=teclat.hasNextDouble();                  
                if(llegit) {                        
                    arrayNotes[i]=teclat.nextDouble();
                
                }else {     
                    
               System.out.print("El valor introducido no es un real, inténtalo de nuevo: ");
                    teclat.next();
                }
            }               
        }           
        //calculaMax();
        return arrayNotes;
    }
    
    public double calculaMax() {
        
        double MAX=0;
        double arrayNotes1[]=new double[5];
        
        arrayNotes1=llegirDades();
        
        for(int i=1;i<arrayNotes1.length-1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<arrayNotes1.length;j++) {
                
                if(arrayNotes1[i]<arrayNotes1[j]) {
                    
                    arrayNotes1[j]=MAX;
                }                               
            }           
        }
        
        imprimir();
        return MAX;
    }       
    
    public void imprimir() {    
    
        double max=calculaMax();    
                
        System.out.print("La nota máxima es: " + max);          
    }               
}
```

Espero poder ayudado es algo complejo.

Comment: Gracias @Christian